# mysql query with multiple table joins with multi-table OR condition in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this legacy sql but it just doesn't seem right. The where clause has conditions for all 3 tables with an OR clause between them, I believe that the records for the conditions for t2 and t3 will not be picked up at all. am I right?

```
SELECT 
    t1.field1, t1.field2
FROM
    table1 t1
LEFT JOIN
    table2 t2 ON t1.t1_id = t2.t2_ref_id
LEFT JOIN
    table3 t3 ON t2.t2_id = t3.t3_ref_id
WHERE
    t1.datetimef1 > '2016-11-01 09:45:00'
        OR t2.datetimef2 > '2016-11-01 09:45:00'
        OR t3.datetimef3 > '2016-11-01 09:45:00'
GROUP BY t1.field1
ORDER BY t1.field1 DESC
```

Comment: The query looks fine to me.

Comment: The query is syntactically correct. Whether it produces the results you expect it to do is a different question, which we cannot answer, since we do not know what this query is supposed to do.

Comment: Two observations: 1. You have a GROUP BY clause but no aggregating functions. This is often symptomatic of a flawed understanding of the GROUP BY clause. 2. I find `LEFT JOIN` with `WHERE` and `OR` problematic. That's not to say that it's wrong. I just struggle to comprehend it. Maybe others do too. Further you select no columns from table3, which, in the context of an OUTER JOIN, is odd.

Comment: I suspect that you would do better to see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query